# What is the Biblical Basis for a “holding place” before life?

Tags: bible, pre-existence

What is the biblical basis for a "place" babies or new souls are held until life (whenever the soul enters the body of the person) according to the Bible?

Comment: I’ve edited your question in an attempt to make it less opinion based. Please let me know if any of the changes go against your original intent.

Comment: Is there a denomination that teaches this?

Comment: Are you inquiring about beliefs in a [pre-mortal existence](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/premortality?lang=eng)?